How to show a file’s enclosing folder in the Files app on iOS without opening the file?
I am working on a SwiftUI app for iOS, where I need to create a text file and then allow the user to navigate to the folder containing that file in the Files app. The app should go to the background and show the folder in Files, similar to the "Show in Finder" functionality on macOS.
Here’s what I’ve tried:
Code for Saving the File:
func saveText(fileName: String, fileString: String, completion: (URL) -> Void) {
    if let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).txt")
        do {
            try fileString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
            print("File successfully created at: \(fileURL)")
            completion(fileURL)
        } catch {
            print("Error writing to file: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

Code for Showing the Folder: I tried using UIApplication.shared.open to open the enclosing directory:
func showInEnclosingFolder(url: URL?) {
    if let validURL = url {
        let directoryURL = validURL.deletingLastPathComponent()
        UIApplication.shared.open(directoryURL, options: [:]) { success in
            if success {
                print("Opened the directory successfully.")
            } else {
                print("Failed to open the directory.")
            }
        }
    }
}

Info.plist Settings: I added these keys to Info.plist:
<key>UIFileSharingEnabled</key>
<true/>
<key>LSSupportsOpeningDocumentsInPlace</key>
<true/>

However, calling UIApplication.shared.open results in the error:
"Failed to open the directory."
What I Need Help With:
Is there a way to show the enclosing folder of a file in the Files app on iOS without opening the file?
Are there additional settings or a different approach I should use to make this work?
Here is the complete code for the app:
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var fileURL: URL? = nil

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Save Text") {
                saveText(fileName: "MyText", fileString: "Hello, world!") { url in
                    fileURL = url
                }
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)

            Button("Show in Enclosing Folder") {
                showInEnclosingFolder(url: fileURL)
            }
            .buttonStyle(.borderedProminent)
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

func saveText(fileName: String, fileString: String, completion: (URL) -> Void) {
    if let documentDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first {
        let fileURL = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent("\(fileName).txt")
        do {
            try fileString.write(to: fileURL, atomically: true, encoding: .utf8)
            print("File successfully created at: \(fileURL)")
            completion(fileURL)
        } catch {
            print("Error writing to file: \(error)")
        }
    }
}

func showInEnclosingFolder(url: URL?) {
    if let validURL = url {
        let directoryURL = validURL.deletingLastPathComponent()
        UIApplication.shared.open(directoryURL, options: [:]) { success in
            if success {
                print("Opened the directory successfully.")
            } else {
                print("Failed to open the directory.")
            }
        }
    } else {
        print("No file URL available.")
    }
}

Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated! (iOS 15.0)

too bad you require iOS15, because with iOS17 it's just a oneliner using .fileImporter.
